# INSERT SELECT vs BATCH INSERT

Tags: mysql

I have a question, does MySQL re-construct the query:

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1
```

Into a batch insert:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUE (1,2),(3,4)
```

?

Because I noticed that inserting with BATCH INSERT is much faster than INSERT SELECT.

Comment: Well in the case of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` MySQL has to go off and run an actual query to get the values first.  I would expect that its performance would be at the whim of the performance of the underlying query.  Of course, it you hard code values in a "batch" insert, then no query is required.